# Regexp for a string

Tags: mysql, regex

I want a regular expression to match all strings like 'T' OR 'T-Th' but NOT values containing only 'Th'

my current regexp is this one:

```
REGEXP = '[T-Th]'
```

but it matches all strings 'T' , 'T-Th' and 'Th' which 'Th' is not desirable

Comment: This isn't exactly clear. Can you post specific complete examples of strings that should match and examples of those which should be rejected?

Comment: `[T-Th]` is the same as `[Th]` (which matches T or h, not "Th").

Comment: i would like to match strings such as 'T' , 'T-Th' but not strings containing only the value 'Th'

Comment: @ather0s Provide *samples* in the question.

Comment: You mean literally `T` or `T-Th`, rather than words beginning with or containing `T` or `Th` as the `[]` character kind of implies?

Answer (score 1):

```
REGEXP = '(T-Th|T[^h])'
```

We either match `T-Th` literally, OR match `T` that is not followed by anything but an `h`.  In other words: `T`, `T-Th`, but not `Th`.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wM8cY1)

Answer (score 1):

If I have the logic correct, you want a `'T'` in the string and you want a `'T'` not followed by `'h'`:

```
where col like '%T%' and
      replace(col, 'Th', '') like '%T%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-` character between brackets is special for regex. It must be escaped when the use is literal. A good alternative for your problem could be this:

```
REGEXP = '(T-Th|T(?!h))'
```

Comment: The `-` is only special inside a character class.

Comment: Aside from the escaping not needed, I think this might be what the OP is asking for...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wrong information is still wrong and should be corrected before being accepted. Otherwise you ingest poison with an otherwise good bottle of wine.

Comment: @user2864740 I don't disagree. My comment was more pointing the fact that the question is still really unclear.

Comment: Actually @user2864740 was right, but with backslash works also. Corrected!